# nuxt styles won't be applied in production mode

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, postcss, postcss-loader

it is been about four months that i am working on this project. it is totally okay in development version but when i build the project and upload it to server **some of my styles won't be applied**.

*for more information* i have imported styles both in components.

```
<style>
</style>
```

and assets css file.
`assets\css\style.css`

i don't know is it right to do or not?

i get this error for the first time i type `npm run build` in vs code terminal

> first time npm run build

```
**✖ Nuxt Fatal Error**                                                                                         
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir                                                               
'C:\Users\rsh\folder\project\.nuxt\components'
```

---

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\rsh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-17T10_43_05_599Z-debug.log
```

---

but for the second time it will build the project within a few warnings.

> when it is built after second try `npm run build`

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
 fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.b26c938.eot (550 KiB)
 fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.3073b3f.woff (265 KiB)
 fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.bfd0d90.ttf (550 KiB)
fonts/icofont.9c33516.woff2 (525 KiB)
fonts/icofont.dad3acc.woff (630 KiB)
img/signin.1455693.svg (846 KiB)
6871893.js (376 KiB)
f031b5e.js (369 KiB)
bc52125.js (376 KiB)
0a7bf8a.js (371 KiB)
20d9dc3.js (673 KiB)
4ab266a.js (401 KiB)
5e1927c.js (1.35 MiB)
6796184.js (2.52 MiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the    recommended limit (1000 KiB). This can impact web performance.
  Entrypoints:
  app (3.42 MiB)
  7f9ae0b.js
  4fe44c5.js
  6796184.js
  20d9dc3.js
```

---

> after `npm run build`

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                  friendly-errors 14:13:07


ERROR  in ./.nuxt/views/app.template.html                                              friendly-errors 14:13:07

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin /lib/loader.js):            friendly-errors 14:13:07
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users \rsh\project1\.nuxt\views\app.template.html'
                                                                                    friendly-errors 14:13:07

ERROR  in ./.nuxt/client.js                                                             friendly-errors 14:13:07

  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):                    friendly-errors 14:13:07
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\rsh\project1\.nuxt\client.js'
                                                                                    friendly-errors 14:13:07
 @ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify- eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000& ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
                                                                                           friendly-errors 14:13:07
 error
```

---

when i type `nuxt build` in vs code terminal
i get this error

> with nuxt build

```
  nuxt : The term 'nuxt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or    operable program. 
  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  At line:1 char:1
  + nuxt build
  + ~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nuxt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

i would really appreaciate it if someone can help me with it or just share same experience

Comment: I am also running into similar issue, I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72198087/7584240 can you please have a look and provide some response? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved my issue by adding this paragraph to `nuxt.config.js` build configuration.

that's actually what i figured out about it. i've had imported my styles inline,in assets files and Vue components style tag this code will  extract all my CSS to a single file (according to [Nuxt documention](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/)) and sync development vs production styles and overwrite styles over `Vuetify`.

```
 extractCSS: {
  ignoreOrder: true
},
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      styles: {
        name: 'styles',
        test: /\.(css|vue)$/,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
      }
    }
  }
},
```

i hope this would help you too.